# Creating an FFMPEG command for setting all videos to the same size and adding an watermark?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, media, watermark

I'm writing a Java app that uses at some point an ffMPEG command in the console. This command needs to do the following:

- Take the input file from `DDTV/episodes-unconverted/example.[mpg/avi]`
- Make it 1280x780. (If it's 4:3, add pillar boxes, if it's 16:9... just you know do nothing I guess)
- Add the watermark `DDTV/DDTVwatermark.png` at 10px from the bottom, and 10px from the right, at 33% transparency to the video.
- Output it to `DDTV/episodes-converted/example.mpg`

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work :

```
ffmpeg -i "DDTV/DDTVwatermark.png" -i "DDTV/episodes-unconverted/example.mpg" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]colorchannelmixer=0.33[ov];[1:v]scale=iw*sar*min(1280/(iw*sar)\,780/ih):ih*min(1280/(iw*sar)\,780/ih),pad=1280:780:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black[mainv];[ov][mainv]overlay=main-w-10:main_h-10[video_out] \
-map [video_out] -map 1:a DDTV/episodes-converted/example.mpg
```

If you want to addd more output option(like codec) put it here in following command :

```
-filter_complex "~" -map [video_out] -map 1:a -c:v mpeg2video -c:a mp3 DDTV/episodes-converted/example.mpg
```

Actually, you can put it anywhere in command line but it just conventional thing. and don't use copy in this case. you can't copy input codec because you're using filter. copy option only works when no filter is used.

let me know if you have any further question.